# Why Right margin doesn't get aligned when this HTML code is used?

Tags: html, css

```
<table width="1168px" height="315px" bgcolor="#eeeeee" style="position:absolute;  top:19px; margin-left:96px; margin-right:96px;" >
```

The table gets left aligned by 96 pixels but it extends until the end on the right side! I haven't specified width for the entire webpage. What did I do wrong? Thanks.

Comment: ... try adding to the style tag-  'margin: auto'

Comment: **Note:** `px` is not a valid unit inside the `width` and `height` HTML attributes - they only take a plain number, representing the number of pixels, or a percentage. They also happen to be deprecated on tables. You really should use CSS instead.

Answer (score 0):

Remove these from the style:

```
position:absolute;
top:19px;
margin-left:96px;
margin-right:96px;
```

And change to:

```
width: 75%;
margin: auto;
```

Also, remove your `width` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

this issue is arising from your WIDTH. If you change this, you should get the desired result. I suggest you make it a % rather than a fixed value.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<table width="500px" height="315px" bgcolor="#eeeeee" style="  top:19px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" >
```